# Why do we need to set the request body as a UTF-8 string when testing the POST method in mockmvc

Tags: java, spring, testing, http-post, mockmvc

I would like to know how to test POST method so I am reading this [article](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/testing/spring-boot-mockmvc-example/#highlighter_618053:%7E:text=The%20HTTP%20POST%20API%20is%20defined%20in%20controller%20is%3A) and this test looks like this:

```
@Test
public void createEmployeeAPI() throws Exception 
{
  mvc.perform( MockMvcRequestBuilders
      .post("/employees")
      .content(asJsonString(new EmployeeVO(null, "firstName4", "lastName4", "email4@mail.com")))
      .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
      .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
      .andExpect(status().isCreated())
      .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.employeeId").exists());
}
 
public static String asJsonString(final Object obj) {
    try {
        return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(obj);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

I don't understand what this line of code is for and what exactly it does: `.content(asJsonString(new EmployeeVO(null, "firstName4", "lastName4", "email4@mail.com")))`

`content(String content)` from the documentation:

"Set the request body as a UTF-8 String.
If content is provided and contentType(MediaType) is set to application/x-www-form-urlencoded, the content will be parsed and used to populate the request parameters map."

Comment: What is your question ? That's a post body to the request

Comment: My question is why do we need to set the request body as a UTF-8 string (so why we should use `content` method). But after your comment I already know the response: to set the request body of POST method. I didn't know that `content` creates request body, I thought it only sets the request body to UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand what this line of code is for and what exactly it does: .content(asJsonString(new EmployeeVO(null, "firstName4", "lastName4", "email4@mail.com")))

Assume that your rest api expects a POST request with Json Body.

The method `content` expects a body as string and `asJsonString` return a json string from the object EmployeeVO with helper ObjectMapper from Jackson library.